# FBSDKSharePhoto caption not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share a photo to Facebook with a ShareDialog, this is my code -

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = takeShot()
photo.caption = blessing.text
photo.userGenerated = true

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [photo]
FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

The problem is that when the ShareDialog appears I can only see the photo, the caption does not show?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share silently with out any FB Dialog screen then use "shareWithContent" as below, but you need to submit your Facebook app for review.

**Code in Obj-c**

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
sharePhoto.caption = @"Test Caption";
sharePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BGI.jpg"];

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[sharePhoto];

[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

**Code in Swift**

```
var sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
sharePhoto.caption = "Test"
sharePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "BGI.jpg")

var content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [sharePhoto]

FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```